# Determining if client is Azure AD joined using dsregcmd fails if called from a script

Tags: azure, windows-domain, azure-activedirectory

We need to test if customer PCs/Laptops meet certain criteria, and one of them is they must have a device that's domain joined - no home users, no serverless non-domain scenarios.

With Azure, the way to check is to query "dsregcmd /status | find /I "AzureAdJoin", then look for the result, which can be piped out to a file.

Won't do it - does not produce any result unless it's in a batch file that runs by clicking the.bat file. Calling the batch file, no dice.

For non Azure/trad server machine, piece of cake. The App checks domain joined or not and errors out if not. But someone could have a corp laptop that is Azure but not "domain joined", no AD, so effectively a BYOD device or other not-really-domain machine.

Is there a way...or am I missing something.  We don't want some intern on a BYOD machine being able to use software that's meant for Admins with full domain access.

Comment: If the real condition is full domain access, then why not check whether they *actually have access* to some specific AD resource instead?

Comment: @user1686  Such as what?  These are not customers we site visit nor have prerequisite other than supported Windows client OS.  Not snark, but what would that be in your judgement?

Is a check of Win32_ComputerSystem enough when it comes to Azure AD joined?  We do check that.

Comment: Addendum, would finding this be proof (even though can be manually added so not bulletproof)  

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\CloudDomainJoin\JoinInfo

Comment: Well, you say that the program is meant for Domain Admins, so I assume it does something that requires Domain Admin privileges? In that case, what harm would there be in "some intern on a BYOD machine" opening the app, if they already have no AD-level privileges do do anything through it? Alternatively -- if the program requires AD specifically, why not try to retrieve some data from AD directory (e.g. look up the rootDSE entry, which is universally present and accessible), and if the lookup fails that implies it's a non-AD machine?

Comment: (And, frankly, a broad "is the machine AD-joined" condition can never be bulletproof because if said 'intern' cares enough, they can just set up AD for free at home...)

Comment: @user1686 Not hypothetical and not snark on 'intern'.  The nature of the software is that information is gathered inside their network (whatever flavor or network), and it's encrypted.  What gets installed can read that data,  Hence, need to prevent installs outside that network so the data is inaccessible, and first step is are they even on a network. Distinguishing kind of network is defeated AFAIK  if it's generically Azure.

Comment: If your program can just straight up decrypt the collected data, does that mean it just comes with the same key embedded for all customers? That sounds like a serious problem in itself. What happens if the software is installed by someone who happens to be a Domain Admin on a completely different domain – can they use it to decrypt data collected by everyone else? (Even if installation aborts, the key is _already_ in the wrong person's hands...) Why isn't the app requiring the encryption key to be provided *by* the domain admins? (That would be a 100% reliable solution, no AD detection.)

Comment: Sorry for asking more questions than providing answers, but from the beginning and the more you talk about the program's design, the more it sounds like an _extreme_ "red flag" case.

Comment: @user1686
No it isn't.  The need is that install is on a domain joined PC by an Administrator and even then we need to give them a key file (separate encryption) that ONLY works for them on that PC.  So, don't assume.  But 1st step is DON'T RUN if not on a domain.